# Enabling Change Tracking for Entity

Tags: cds, common-data-service, dataverse

Is there a way to enable change tracking for couple of entities programmatically? I could not find any api in [Dataverse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/web-api/about?view=dynamics-ce-odata-9) which can help to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[You cannot do that with webapi](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/data-platform/use-change-tracking-synchronize-data-external-systems#enable-change-tracking-for-an-entity) but you can definitely achieve this programatically.

you can either create console application or you can run [code now plugin for xrmtoolbox](https://www.xrmtoolbox.com/plugins/TreeCat.XrmToolBox.CodeNow/) and get this done.

Below code snippet for reference.

```
UpdateEntityRequest updateBankAccountRequest = new UpdateEntityRequest
{
     Entity = BankAccountEntity,
     ChangeTrackingEnabled = true //or false here
};

_serviceProxy.Execute(updateBankAccountRequest);
```

[Microsoft docs for ChangeTrackingEnabled](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.xrm.sdk.metadata.entitymetadata.changetrackingenabled?view=dynamics-general-ce-9#Microsoft_Xrm_Sdk_Metadata_EntityMetadata_ChangeTrackingEnabled)